# leaflet js map not showing fully on page load

Tags: jquery, laravel, leaflet

on loading a page load my leaflet map is unable to load fully and instead it shows a small section of the map.but when I try to resize the screen the map fully shows as a whole.i don't understand why yet i have initialized the map correctly in the script.this is my codebase where might be doing it wrong.i have added the necessary leaflet js and CSS cdn links[image]
this is my HTML

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 40px 5px;">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="ms_heading">
            <h3 class="text-white p-2">properties Locations</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="map"
            style="height: 400px; margin-top:5px;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my script

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        //1. initialize leaflet map
        var center = [-0.421498116026705, 36.950147769312004];
        var propertiesmap = L.map('map').setView(center, 10);

        propertiesmap.invalidateSize();

        var googleStreets = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
            maxZoom: 10,
            subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
        });

        googleStreets.addTo(propertiesmap)

        var marker = L.marker([-0.421498116026705, 36.950147769312004]).addTo(propertiesmap);
                
    });
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/uYKdPouxCGfQ6nxI)

Comment: @IvanSanchez what might the probable issue causing it not fully load in my side

Comment: @Mehran I removed but still doesnt fully load

Comment: The most probable cause is that the code you posted here is not the code you're using there.

Comment: @IvanSanchez its still the one..on large screen the map isn't displaying but on a small screen it works perfectly

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Answer (score 1):

Check the leaflet.css that is loaded correctly? I had similar problem and fixed now.

Comment: yes i have checked but still the page doesn't load fully     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />

Answer (score 0):

this code help me

```
setTimeout(function () {
 window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?